# Get the first letter of each 2-letter word in python

Tags: python, list

I have this code:

```
hand=["TS","AD"]
test=['--23456789TJQKA'.index(a) for a, b in hand]
print (test)
```

result is :

```
[10, 14]
```

How does this snippet work? Is it a built-in function for [a for a, b in list]   to get the first letter of each 2-letter word in list in python?

Comment: For the record, while this code _works_, it's not _good_. It's somewhat obscure to split each card into `a, b` instead of just using `card[0]` (especially calling them `a` and `b` instead of, say, `value` and `suit`), a `dict` would do the job better than a `list`, and wrapping it in a function with a name instead of trying to cram it into an expression split between the two halves of a listcomp isn't helping readability.

Comment: Also defining `'--23456789TJQKA'` once prior to the list comprehension would stop it being recreated on each iteration (unless python is doing some funky internal optimization). Not really an issue for 2 iterations, but still worth noting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, let's turn the code into a for loop:

```
hand = ["TS","AD"]
test = []
for a,b in hand:
    test.append('--23456789TJQKA'.index(a))
# note that we didn't use b

print(test)
```

So what's happening here?
Well, each element in `hand` is an iterable with two elements. This means that `for a,b in hand` iterates through each string in `hand`, assigning the first character to `a` and the second to `b`. This is effectively the same as:

```
for mystr in hand:
    a = mystr[0]
    b = mystr[1]
    # or equivalently, a,b = mystr
```

The next piece is `'--23456789TJQKA'.index(a)`, which simply returns the index of the first occurrence of `a` in string `'--23456789TJQKA'`.

So the output ends up being a list of two numbers - the indices of the first character of each string in `hand`, namely, `'T'` and `'A'`

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response.  So could I understand in this way, for string in python, it can be considered as a list and each letter is a list value?

Comment: @Echo: yes, you could think of it that way. As a matter of fact, strings are represented as arrays (*ahem* lists) of letters in many languages including C, which is what python itself is implemented in. The most immediate difference between a list and a string is that strings are immutable - i.e. while you can do `myList[2] = 'a'`, you can't do `myString[2] = 'a'`

Answer (score 2):

This is a normal list comprehension that is splitting the two letter strings in hand into tuple of letters

for the first element of hand:

```
a, b in 'TS'
# a == 'T'
# b == 'S'

'--23456789TJQKA'.index('T')
# 10
```

for the second element of hand:

```
a, b in 'AD'
# a == 'A'
# b == 'D'

'--23456789TJQKA'.index('A')
# 14
```

Answer (score 0):

Here `for a, b in hand` part actually unpacks the strings `TS` and `AD`. loop variable `a` and `b` is assigned to a `hand` element. Which is like

```
(a, b) = 'TS'
```

here a is assigned to `T` and b is set to `S`.

After that `.index` method just looks for `a` and returns the index of it.

Note: This will not work if `hand` contains a non-two letter word.

Answer (score 0):

The code has something to do with poker or some other card game using a standard 52 card deck. `test` will be a list of the ordinal "ranks" of a player's hand (the "suit" is not saved). It uses tuple unpacking to put the "rank" of the hand into `a` and the "suit" into `b` within the list comprehension.

Comment: Yes it's from a poker program. But I just wondering how the algorithm works so it could be applied for more general use.

Comment: Gotcha. I thought you were trying to make sense of some code that you knew nothing about. As noted above that code is not suited for more general use :)